# Aggregate/sum and N/A values

Tags: r

I have a problem with the way aggregate or N/A deals with sums.

I would like the sums per area.code from following table

```
test <- read.table(text = "
area.code   A    B   C   D
1          0  NA 0.00  NA  NA
2          1 0.0 3.10 9.6 0.0
3          1 0.0 3.20 6.0 0.0
4          2 0.0 6.10 5.0 0.0
5          2 0.0 6.50 8.0 0.0
6          2 0.0 6.90 4.0 3.1
7          3 0.0 6.70 3.0 3.2
8          3 0.0 6.80 3.1 6.1
9          3 0.0 0.35 3.2 6.5
10         3 0.0 0.67 6.1 6.9
11         4 0.0 0.25 6.5 6.7
12         5 0.0 0.68 6.9 6.8
13         6 0.0 0.95 6.7 0.0
14         7 1.2   NA 6.8 0.0
")
```

So, seems pretty easy:

```
aggregate(.~area.code, test, sum)



area.code A     B    C    D
1         1 0  6.30 15.6  0.0
2         2 0 19.50 17.0  3.1
3         3 0 14.52 15.4 22.7
4         4 0  0.25  6.5  6.7
5         5 0  0.68  6.9  6.8
6         6 0  0.95  6.7  0.0
```

Apparently not so simple, because area code 7 is completely omitted from the aggregate() command.

I would however like the N/As to be completely ignored or computed as zero values, which na= command gives that option?

replacing all N/As with 0 is an option if I just want the sum... but the mean is really problematic then (since it can't differentiate between 0 and N/A anymore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to consider an external package (`data.table`):

```
setDT(test)
test[, lapply(.SD, sum), area.code]
   area.code   A     B    C    D
1:         0  NA  0.00   NA   NA
2:         1 0.0  6.30 15.6  0.0
3:         2 0.0 19.50 17.0  3.1
4:         3 0.0 14.52 15.4 22.7
5:         4 0.0  0.25  6.5  6.7
6:         5 0.0  0.68  6.9  6.8
7:         6 0.0  0.95  6.7  0.0
8:         7 1.2    NA  6.8  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use `dplyr`:

```
test %>%
  group_by(area.code) %>%
  summarise_all(sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a function that gives `NA` when all the values are `NA` or otherwise use `sum`.  Along with that, use `na.action` argument in `aggregate` as `aggregate` can remove the row if there is at least one NA

```
f1 <- function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)
aggregate(.~area.code, test, f1, na.action = na.pass)
# area.code   A     B    C    D
#1         0  NA  0.00   NA   NA
#2         1 0.0  6.30 15.6  0.0
#3         2 0.0 19.50 17.0  3.1
#4         3 0.0 14.52 15.4 22.7
#         4 0.0  0.25  6.5  6.7
#6         5 0.0  0.68  6.9  6.8
#7         6 0.0  0.95  6.7  0.0
#8         7 1.2    NA  6.8  0.0
```

---

When there are only `NA` elements and we use `sum` with `na.rm = TRUE`, it returns 0

```
sum(c(NA, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 0
```